# Why does saving a loaded Bitmap increase it's size?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-resources

I load a png file from the sdcard. I alter it in someway and then save it again. I have noticed that the saved file is much larger than the original.

At first I thought it was because of modifying the file. Then I tested with the code below and still happens.

I just load a png file and then save it with another name.

The Original file is **32Kb** and the Saved file is **300Kb**.
Any ideas?

```
     try
     {  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Original.png");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Saved.png"); 
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
     } 
     catch (Exception e)
     {  //Never gets here
     }
```

Comment: That's because you're specifying a quality of 100. The lesser the quality the smaller your file

Comment: With PNG files that parameter is ignored. I don't want to modify the quality (not smaller but not larger either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the size of your `Bitmap` by the **compress factor** (quality):

```
Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, FileOutputStream out);
```

100 = maximum quality, 0 = low quality.

Try like "10" or something to keep your image smaller.
It could also be that you are loading a Bitmap that is in **16-Bit** color and than later save it in **32-Bit** color, increasing its size.

Check `BitmapConfig.RGB_565`, `BitmapConfig.ARGB_4444` and `BitmapConfig.ARGB_8888` respectively.

EDIT:

Here is how to load Bitmaps correctly:

```
public abstract class BitmapResLoader {

    public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromResource(Bitmap.Config config, Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = config;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    private static int calculateInSampleSize(
                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

In code:

```
// Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 = 16 Bit
Bitmap b = BitmapResLoader.decodeBitmapFromResource(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, getResources(), width, height);
```

That way, you can control how your `Bitmap` is loaded into Memory (see `Bitmap.Config`).